# Split selected feature with selected line from another layer in QGIS LTR 3.4.9

Tags: qgis-3, digitizing

[image: This is the tool I need from 2.14 release][image: Screenshot of my digitizing toolbar]Can't seem to find that tool since I switched from QGIS 2.14 to 3.4.9
It doesn't seem to be included in the Advance Digitizing Toolbar like before.For now, I re-installed 2.14 since I need to use this tool but I would like to know how/if I can have it in the latest LTR 3.4.9 Madeira ? First picture is 2.14.22, second picture is 3.4.9 with the same toolbar missing the tool.

Comment: That's included in the **Digitizing Tools** plugin which can be enabled from the menubar: `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins`

Comment: I know, I did but somehow this particular tool is not present in the toolbar and I can't seem to find it anywhere.